# Oracle lookup produces baffling result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have records like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(JOB_DEFINITION) VALUES ('JobDefinition://company/apps/team/crmCommon/workMgmt/assignmentMgr/ObjectShareBatchAssignRequest');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(JOB_DEFINITION) VALUES ('JobDefinition://company/apps/team/financials/commonModules/metrics/GenerateFinMetrics');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(JOB_DEFINITION) VALUES ('JobDefinition://company/apps/team/financials/subledgerAccounting/shared/XLAOTEC');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(JOB_DEFINITION) VALUES ('JobDefinition://company/apps/team/fnd/applcore/FndIDCSSyncNotifyServiceJob');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(JOB_DEFINITION) VALUES ('JobDefinition://company/apps/team/fnd/applcore/FndOSCSAttachmentIngestJob');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(JOB_DEFINITION) VALUES ('JobDefinition://company.apps.team.biccc/BICloudConnectorJobDefinition');
```

And I need to run a regex on the values, and then do a lookup/mapping on the regex. It's the lookup that produces baffling results.

So, query with regex:

```sql
select JOB_DEFINITION, 
regexp_replace(JOB_DEFINITION, 'Job.*://company[/\.][a-z]+[/\.]team[/\.]([a-zA-Z_]+)/?(.*)$', '\1') as ep
from MY_TABLE;
```

produces:

| JOB_DEFINITION | EP |
| --- | --- |
| JobDefinition://company/apps/team/financials/commonModules/metrics/GenerateFinMetrics | financials |
| JobDefinition://company/apps/team/financials/subledgerAccounting/shared/XLAOTEC | financials |
| JobDefinition://company/apps/team/fnd/applcore/FndIDCSSyncNotifyServiceJob | fnd |
| JobDefinition://company/apps/team/fnd/applcore/FndOSCSAttachmentIngestJob | fnd |
| JobDefinition://company.apps.team.biccc/BICloudConnectorJobDefinition | biccc |
| JobDefinition://company/apps/team/cdm/dataStewardship/batchEnrichmeąntProcteam/ScheduledAccountEnrichmentJob | cdm |

So far, so good.

The problem now comes in where I want to take the `ep` and do a static lookup:

```sql
select met.job_definition, regex.ep,lookup.family
from (select NVL(regexp_replace(JOB_DEFINITION, 'Job.*://company[/\.][a-z]+[/\.]team[/\.]([a-zA-Z_]+)/?(.*)$', '\1'),'TBD') as ep
      from MY_TABLE) regex,
     (select 'cdm' as ExtractedProduct, 'CRM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'crm' as ExtractedProduct, 'CRM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'crmCommon' as ExtractedProduct, 'CRM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'financials' as ExtractedProduct, 'ERP' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'custom' as ExtractedProduct, 'Custom' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'fnd' as ExtractedProduct, 'ApplCore' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'hcm' as ExtractedProduct, 'HCM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'incentiveCompensation' as ExtractedProduct, 'ERP' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'marketing' as ExtractedProduct, 'CRM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'prc' as ExtractedProduct, 'SCM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'projects' as ExtractedProduct, 'ERP' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'sales' as ExtractedProduct, 'CRM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'scm' as ExtractedProduct, 'SCM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'search' as ExtractedProduct, 'ApplCore' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'psc' as ExtractedProduct, 'ERP' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'contracts' as ExtractedProduct, 'CRM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'extn' as ExtractedProduct, 'Custom' as Family
      from dual) lookup,
     MY_TABLE met
where regex.ep = lookup.ExtractedProduct
```

which produces:

| JOB_DEFINITION | EP | FAMILY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JobDefinition://company/apps/team/hcm/batchProcesses/core/ArchiveWriteJob | financials | ERP |

Which is obviously not right: This should be `hcm`

Am I somehow doing this join wrong?

I basically have 3 sets of data:

- The regex for a given data
- raw data itself
- the lookup

Comment: You list `MY_TABLE met` in the `from` clause, but there's no join to that table. Oracle is probably producing a cartesian product as a result.

Comment: I am sure you're right, but I join them at the outer most level.

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno - no you don't. You have `from (...) regex, (...) lookup, MY_TABLE met` but the only implicit join condition is `regex.ep = lookup.ExtractedProduct`. There is no condition relating `met` to either `regex` or `lookup`.

Comment: It doesn't look like you need that join though - you can remove it and get project `job_definition` in the `regex` inline view instead? As nbk's answer shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

comma seprated table, mean always CROCROSS JOIN which produces a cartesian  product.

Using proper JOIN  will prevent such a thing

```
select regex.job_definition,regex.ep,lookup.family
from (select JOB_DEFINITION,NVL(regexp_replace(JOB_DEFINITION, 'Job.*://company[/\.][a-z]+[/\.]team[/\.]([a-zA-Z_]+)/?(.*)$', '\1'),'TBD') as ep
      from MY_TABLE) regex JOIN
     (select 'cdm' as ExtractedProduct, 'CRM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'crm' as ExtractedProduct, 'CRM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'crmCommon' as ExtractedProduct, 'CRM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'financials' as ExtractedProduct, 'ERP' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'custom' as ExtractedProduct, 'Custom' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'fnd' as ExtractedProduct, 'ApplCore' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'hcm' as ExtractedProduct, 'HCM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'incentiveCompensation' as ExtractedProduct, 'ERP' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'marketing' as ExtractedProduct, 'CRM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'prc' as ExtractedProduct, 'SCM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'projects' as ExtractedProduct, 'ERP' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'sales' as ExtractedProduct, 'CRM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'scm' as ExtractedProduct, 'SCM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'search' as ExtractedProduct, 'ApplCore' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'psc' as ExtractedProduct, 'ERP' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'contracts' as ExtractedProduct, 'CRM' as Family
      from dual
      union all
      select 'extn' as ExtractedProduct, 'Custom' as Family
      from dual) lookup on  regex.ep = lookup.ExtractedProduct
```

| JOB_DEFINITION | EP | FAMILY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JobDefinition://company/apps/team/crmCommon/workMgmt/assignmentMgr/ObjectShareBatchAssignRequest | crmCommon | CRM |
| JobDefinition://company/apps/team/financials/commonModules/metrics/GenerateFinMetrics | financials | ERP |
| JobDefinition://company/apps/team/financials/subledgerAccounting/shared/XLAOTEC | financials | ERP |
| JobDefinition://company/apps/team/fnd/applcore/FndIDCSSyncNotifyServiceJob | fnd | ApplCore |
| JobDefinition://company/apps/team/fnd/applcore/FndOSCSAttachmentIngestJob | fnd | ApplCore |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/E24InAIX)